# How to use multiple combo boxes to filter data in MS Access?

Tags: database, filter, combobox, ms-access-2007

I am learning MS Access 2007.

I have few tables linked together as follows:

```
OwnerList
ID | Project Owner | Address etc

ProjectList
ID | Project Name | Project Owner (Linked to OwnerList.ID) | etc

PartList
ID | Project Part | Project (linked to ProjectList.ID) | etc

SubpartLIst
ID | Project Subpart | Project Part (linked to PartList.ID) | etc

WorkerList
ID | Worker Name | Address etc

TaskList
ID | Subpart (linked to SubpartList.ID) | Assigned to (Linked to WorkerList.ID) | Work to bo done | etc
```

Now I want to design a Form in which 4 combo box are used:
1. Project Owner (name); 2. Project Name; 3. Project Part; 4. Project Subpart

and all Fields of TaskList.

This form would be filtered by four combobox dynamically and if all four will have been updated then we would fill record for Tasklist.

How to filter each next combobox on updating previous combobox and how to fill records for tasklist table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it. Here is the solution.

I have made 4 combo boxes on my form as below and all fields from the `Tasks` table:

1. Project Owner

Name: `Combo0`

RowSource:

```
    SELECT [Owner List].[Owner ID], [Owner List].[Owner Name]
    FROM [Owner List];
```

Macro->Event->AfterUpdate:

```
    Requery -> Combo2
    Requery -> Combo4
    Requery -> Combo8
```

2. Project Name

Name: `Combo2`

RowSource:

```
    SELECT [Project List].[Project ID], [Project List].[Project Name]
    FROM [Project List]
    WHERE ((([Project List].[Owner ID])=[Forms]![Form1]![combo0]));
```

Macro->Event->AfterUpdate:

```
    Requery -> Combo4
    Requery -> Combo8
```

3. Project Part

Name: `Combo4`

RowSource:

```
    SELECT [Parts List].[Part ID], [Parts List].[Section Name]
    FROM [Project List] RIGHT JOIN [Parts List] ON [Project List].[Project    ID] = [Parts List].[Project ID]
    WHERE ((([Parts List].[Project ID])=[forms]![Form1]![Combo2]) AND (([Project List].[Owner ID])=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo0]));
```

Macro->Event->AfterUpdate:

```
    Requery -> Combo8
```

4. Subpart Name

Name: `Combo8`

RowSource:

```
    SELECT [Subparts List].[Subpart ID], [Subparts List].[Subpart Name]
    FROM [Project List] RIGHT JOIN ([Project Parts] RIGHT JOIN [Subparts List] ON [Project Parts].[Part ID] = [Subparts List].[Part ID]) ON [Project List].[Project ID] = [Project Parts].[Project ID]
    WHERE ((([Subparts List].[Part ID])=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo4]) AND (([Project Parts].[Project ID])=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo2]) AND (([Project List].[Owner ID])=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo0]));
```

Macro->Event->AfterUpdate:

```
    ApplyFilter -> =" [Subpart ID] = " & [Combo8] & ""
```

and the all the values from the `Tasks` table.

Now the steps for filtering are as follows:

1. Select `Owner` from the combo box `Combo0`. After selection of the owner this combo box run a Macro as:

   ```
   Requery -> `Combo2`
   ```

to filter Project List for current `owner`

```
    Requery -> `Combo4`
```

to filter Part List for current `owner`

```
    Requery -> `Combo8`
```

to filter Subpart List for current `owner`

2. Select `Project` from the combo box `Combo2`. After selection of the Project this combo box run another macro:

   ```
   Requery -> `Combo4`
   ```

to filter Part List for current `owner` and `project`

```
    Requery -> `Combo8`
```

to filter Subpart List for current `owner` and `project`

3. Select `Part` from the combo box `Combo4`. After selection of the Part, this combo box run another macro:

   ```
   Requery -> `Combo8`
   ```

to filter Subpart List for current `owner`, `project` and `part`.

4. Select `Sub Part` from the combo box `Combo8`. After selection of the Subpart, this combo box run another macro:

   ```
   ApplyFilter -> =" [Subpart ID] = " & [Combo8] & ""
   ```

for current `owner`, `project`, `part` and `subpart`.

What I could not understand from the already given answers about filtering through combo box is that the given answer is filtering through a String value (The code is `ApplyFilter -> = " [Subpart ID] = '" & [Combo8] & "'"`) of the respective combo box. But I am using number instead of string value as column bound in all four combo boxes which gives the error `data mismatch`. When I remove both `' '` from the code, it successfully filter the records.